# ng -v or ng generate gave the error message TypeError: Cannot read property 'glob' of null

Tags: angular-cli-v6

On my project directory I ran ng -v or ng g service  and got error messages:

```
/users/ui/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/schema-tree.js:229
                this._children[name] = this._createChildProperty(name, value ? value[name] : undefined, forward ? forward.children[name] : null, propertySchema);
                                                                                                                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'glob' of null
    at ObjectSchemaTreeNode._set (/Users/joannepham/git/pws/console-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/schema-tree.js:229:131)
    at new ObjectSchemaTreeNode (/Users/joannepham/git/pws/console-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/schema-tree.js:214:14)
    at OneOfSchemaTreeNode._createChildProperty (/Users/joannepham/git/pws/console-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/schema-tree.js:153:26)
    at OneOfSchemaTreeNode._typesPrototype.schema.oneOf.map (/Users/joannepham/git/pws/console-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/schema-tree.js:166:25)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at new OneOfSchemaTreeNode (/Users/joannepham/git/pws/console-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/schema-tree.js:165:48)
    at ArraySchemaTreeNode._createChildProperty (/Users/joannepham/git/pws/console-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/schema-tree.js:153:26)
    at ArraySchemaTreeNode._set (/Users/joannepham/git/pws/console-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/schema-tree.js:291:39)
    at new ArraySchemaTreeNode (/Users/joannepham/git/pws/console-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/schema-tree.js:272:14)
    at ObjectSchemaTreeNode._createChildProperty (/Users/joannepham/git/pws/console-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/schema-tree.js:153:26)
```

Outside this folder is ok. Any suggestion how to fix this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check it there any hidden `.angular-cli.json` or `angular-cli.json` in your user folder, and check duplicates in your project

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I got the hidden .angular-cli.json file. Deleted this file and everything is worked. Again thanks